# AngularJs - ng - view don't work to me

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning Angularjs and this is my first code, but i can't find the bug, ng-view doesn't show data. I don't know how to debug mi code. 
Please somebody can help me to show data using ng-view?.

This is my code:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="FinalApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialdesignicons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lumx.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>-->  
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular-parse-ext.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lumx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="bgc-black-1 tc-white" flex-container="row" flex-align="center center">
            <div flex-item="4">
                <h1 class="fs-display-3 display-block">Posts App</h1>
            </div>
            <div flex-item="1">
                <a href="#">Inicio</a>              
            </div>
            <div flex-item="1">
                <a href="#">Crear Post</a>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div flex-container="row" flex-aling="center">
        <div ng-view flex-item="9"></div>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**and the controller is**

```
    angular.module('FinalApp')
    .controller('MainController',function($scope,$resource){
    Post = $resource('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/:id',{id:'@id'});
    $scope.posts = Post.query();//agrupamos los posts   
    });
```

**Home.html**

```
    <lx-tabs>
    <lx-tab heading='Posts'>
        <div class='p+'>
            <div class='card' ng-repeat='post in posts'>
                <div class='p+'>
                    <strong class='fs-headline display-block tc-red-900'>
                        {{post.title}}
                    </strong>
                    <div class='paragrah fs-body-1 mt+'>
                        {{post.body}}
                    </div>
                    <div class='card_actions'>
                        <a href='#'>Leer mas</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lx-tab>
    <lx-tab heading='Users'>
        <div class='p+'>
            hello world users
        </div>
    </lx-tab>
</lx-tabs>
```

**App.js**

```
    angular.module('FinalApp',['lumx','ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            controller: 'MainController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        }) 
    });
```

Finally i'm using LumX for make the front end of the application and the version of LumX is v1.5.31

Comment: use chrome developer tools to debug it.https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the working demo, you can find it in the below link!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

I checked your code, there are only some minor corrections.

Instead of defining `angular.module('FinalApp')` differently in different files, try following a syntax like this.

```
var app = angular.module('FinalApp',['ngResource','lumx','ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
            controller: 'MainController',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        }) 
    });

app.controller('MainController',function($scope, $resource){
    var Post = $resource('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/:id',{id:'@id'});
    console.log(Post.query());
    $scope.posts = Post.query();//agrupamos los posts   
});
```

So you define it only once and assign it to a variable, which can be used anywhere in the project, like shown in the above code. Thus the dependencies are always available to all the controllers!

In order to use `$resource` of angular, you need to include the file **[`angular-resource.min.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-resource.min.js)** and also, after including the file you need to add it to the module dependencies.

```
var app = angular.module('FinalApp',['ngResource','lumx','ngRoute']);
```

There is also one minor suggestion I would like to make. It's that the tabs don't have a label. you can define them like so.

```
<lx-tab heading='Users' lx-label="Users">
        <div class='p+'>
            hello world users
        </div>
    </lx-tab>
```

I am using templates in the script tag to create the different pages for the router, you can use the normal method itself, so you

***need to ignore the changes I have made in config section***, I mean the below part.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
            controller: 'MainController',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        }) 
    });
```

Please let me know if it still shows errors, Happy Coding!